# In Performance Monitor, what's the difference between "Cache % Machine Memory Limit Used" and "Cache % Process Memory Limit Used"?

Tags: windows, asp.net

These are both in Performance Monitor, in the category "ASP.NET Applications."

I couldn't find an official reference for these two values. They're substantially different from each other but we're not running multiple websites.